# Node.js send post with array parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello and happy new year!

I'm trying to send a post petition in Node.js. The version I need to replicate in javascript looks like this:

```
$.post('website.com/api/buy.php', {
  action: order,
  'items[]': cart_i,
  time: localtime,
  utb: x //I don't know why that parameter is sent. It's always 0 ._.
} ... //rest of the code of that website
```

I'm trying to do this in Node.js to replicate that:

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
  action: 'order',
  "items[]": item.i,
  time: local_time,
  utb: 0
});
var https = require('https');
var options = { method: 'POST', host: 'website.com', port: 443, path: '/api/buy.php', headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Cookie': cookies, 'Accept': '/', 'Connection': 'keep-alive' } };
var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        content = content+ chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        console.log(content)
    });
}
);
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

But I always get an error telling me that I didnt send anything. I think the problem could be in items[] because I see it sends "items%5B%5D", but I dont know if I'm doing something wrong. I think is is not about cookies, because if I'm not logged I get other error.
I'm doing the request well? Or I'm missing something that is not about the request? Is there other way to send "post" data easier?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you list the full errors in the question?

Comment: What do you mean with the list of errors? The response I get?

Comment: `I always get an error telling me that I didnt send anything`  and `because if I'm not logged I get other error` . Those two errors.

Comment: Yes. This is the responses I get: {"result":"error","message":"No items were selected"} and when I'm not logged I get this: {"result":"error","message":"Not logged in"} I think it's about the array parameter, but I can't tell if it's sending something :(

Comment: Is `item.i` an array?

Comment: No. It's an object: When I do console.log(postData) I get this: action=order&items%5B%5D=569301875208341&time=1515251849&x=0 Edit: I also see you can change / delete time on the javascript and it still works on the website, but not in my node.js request... :(